# How to prove this inequality for the norm $ \|\cdot\|_{1,\infty} $?

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, norms

> Let $ \{a_k\}_{i=1}^n $ is a positive sequence. For $ 0<p<\infty $, space $ L^{p,\infty} $ is defined by
> $$
> \left\{f:\|f\|_{p,\infty}=\inf\left\{C>0:a_f(\lambda)\leq C/\lambda^p\right\}\right\}
> $$
> where
> $$
> a_f(\lambda)=|\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:|f(x)|>\lambda\}|.
> $$
> Then
> $$
> \left\|\sum_{k=1}^{n}f_k\right\|_{1,\infty}\leq \left(1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k\right)\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\ln(1+a_k^{-1})\|f_k\|_{1,\infty}\right)
> $$

I do not know why there are $ a_k $ in the inequality. Can you give me some hints or references?

Comment: This looks very close to the Stein-Weiss inequality, see Lemma 2.3 of https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=241685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $ \lambda>0 $, we have
\begin{align}
\left|\left\{x:\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf_k\right|>\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^na_k\right)\lambda\right\}\right|&\leq\left|\left\{x:\sum_{i=1}^n|f_k|>\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^na_k\right)\lambda\right\}\right|\\
&\leq\left|\left\{x:\sum_{i=1}^n(|f_k|-a_k\lambda)>\lambda\right\}\right|\\
&\leq\left|\left\{x:\sum_{i=1}^n(|f_k|-a_k\lambda)_+>\lambda\right\}\right|.
\end{align}
For any $ \varepsilon>0 $, set
$$
g_k(x)=\min\{(|f_k|-a_k\lambda)_+,\lambda(1+\varepsilon)\}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
\left|\left\{x:\left|\sum_{i=1}^nf_k\right|>\left(1+\sum_{i=1}^na_k\right)\lambda\right\}\right|&\leq\left|\left\{x:\sum_{i=1}^ng_k>\lambda\right\}\right|\\
&\leq\frac{\left\|\sum_{i=1}^ng_k\right\|_{1,\infty}}{\lambda}\\
&\leq\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n\|g_k\|_{1}}{\lambda}.
\end{align}
Finally, note that
\begin{align}
\|g_k\|_1&=\int_{0}^{\lambda(1+\varepsilon)}|\{x:|g_k|>\mu\}|d\mu\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{\lambda(1+\varepsilon)}|\{x:|f_k|>\mu+a_k\lambda\}|d\mu\\
&\leq\int_{0}^{\lambda(1+\varepsilon)}\frac{\|f_k\|_{1,\infty}}{\mu+a_k\lambda}d\mu=\ln\left(\frac{a_k\lambda+\lambda(1+\varepsilon)}{a_k\lambda}\right).
\end{align}
Combining all above and letting $ \varepsilon\to 0 $, we can get the proof.